# Python package installation issues with lib & lib64 in RHEL 7

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, rhel, lib

I am trying to install Python packages like numpy, pandas, etc in my Hadoop cluster which is installed in Red Hat (RHEL 7).
I downloaded tar files, extracted them and then exceuted Python set.py install command to install the package. 
I need guidance on below observations:

1. Pandas dependencies are getting installed under /usr/lib/python 2.7/, while Pandas library is getting installed under /usr/lib64/python 2.7/. 
   Now though I am able to import the dependencies like pytz, six, etc, I am getting import error while trying to import pandas. 
   I am getting same issue while importing other packages like numpy, scipy, etc as they all are getting inst under lib64 folder.
   I added both lib & lib64 folders in sys.path, but it didn't help. Also, tried softlink, but again it didn't help. Please help.
2. How different is lib & lib64 folders? Why does python search for packages i under lib and not lib64, even when PATH variables are set to both the locations?